# Why not use eCDF to choose the model of survivability?

Tags: survival, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have been reading a little bit about survivability and I am a little confused about choosing models. Let me set an experiment:

You run 50 toasters until all of them fail, noting down their lifespan $t_1,\cdots,t_n$. We may now create a eCDF, at each time $t_i$ you can write the proportion that has died of the 50 toaster up until $t_i$. This gives you a rough CDF prediction that is non-parametric. That should give you an idea of what kind of "true" CDF will fit, then you do, say MLE, to figure out the parameters of the CDF you think fits.

Is there anything wrong with this procedure? To my understanding, they always just use Weibull distribution and immediately use MLE (which would be assuming the model, which at first glance should be strictly inferior to doing a eCDF check). Could anyone tell me why that is?

Follow up question, why Duane even bothered with graphing the hazard function (which imo is a weird quantity, instantaneous conditional probability that someone will die in the next moment) When you can just graph the CDF and notice that it looks like an exponential/weibull (if it does in fact look like it).

Comment: Sorry, who is Duane?

Comment: @wzbillings The Duane Model.  J. T. Duane is the guys name. He graphed 1/hazard rate vs cumulative time on log log scale and noticed its a line lol.